# Fetch and Compare Key and Value from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to make an app in which user store his Data. I've used user shared preferences to save user login details but still for security purpose, i made an activity(Verify Passcode Activity) that ask user Passcode to allow access on the data. Now i'm able to save, fetch and delete data. But in my Verify Passcode Activity, i just want to fetch that particular key and value where passcode is stored. I don't want to fetch complete data in Verify Passcode Activity.

Below is the code which i used to save passcode to database:-

```
databaseReference.child(uniqueID).setValue(passcode);
```

Below is the code i'm tried to fetch only passcode:-

```
dbreference.child(uniqueID).orderByChild("passcode").equalTo(pass).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data doesn't exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Here `uniqueID` is `"abhishek88666kumar"`and `pass` is a variable used for `getText()`.

Here is the screenshot of my Firebase Database :-

[Database Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7itFZ.png)

Here is Verify Passcode Activity Screenshot:-

[image: Verify Passcode Activity Screenshot]

Please have a look at Database Screenshot and Verify Passcode Activity Screenshot.

Agenda:

1. getText() from textView inside activity.
2. getValue from firebase realtime database (only for current user. 'abhishek88666kumar' in our case).
3. compare if 1 and 2 are same or not. (If same then redirect to MainActivity else show error.)

Please tell me what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all for your help :) Your answer didn't worked for me but with the help of your answers and my few knowledge, I made a solution for my problem myself.
Here is the code that matches my requirement. This code is working exactly how I wanted.

```
dbreference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("passcodes");
                    Query query = dbreference.orderByKey().equalTo(currentUser); //current user is "abhishek88666kumar" in this case.
                    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                                String passcode = txtPasscode.getText().toString;//Passcode is 1234 in this case.
                                String fetchedValue = "";
                                for (DataSnapshot snap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                    fetchedValue = (String) snap.getValue();
                                }
                                if (!passcode.equals(fetchedValue)){
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Passcode doesn't match.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }else{
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Passcode matched.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No passcode found for this user", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `pass` is a value like `1234`,  this line:

```
dbreference.child(uniqueID).orderByChild("passcode").equalTo(pass).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...
```

Should be:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("passcodes").orderByValue().equalTo(pass).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...
```

This way the `DataSnapshot` will contain all child nodes of `passcodes` that have the value `1234`, i.e. `"abhishek88666kumar"` in your JSON sample.

Also be sure to study the [documentation on sorting and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).

Comment: Thanks for giving your time to reply. Please have a look at updated Database Screenshot. Now in my database, we have total 4 user passcode. From which, two users "abhishek88666kumar" and "rohit88666kumar" have same passcode. So if I use your provided code then database will check "Passcodes" for value 1234 but because it have two users with same passcode, it may affect validation. Also, Suppose ''abhishek88666kumar" passcode is 1234 but he enters 3328 which is kalpeshchaudhary8's passcode. In that case, database will return true because database have 3328. What to do?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. In Firebase terms the key `abhishek88666kumar` has nothing to do with a user, and can be easily spoofed by any user.

Answer (score 0):

> This is the first way to compare firebase data.

```
btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                passcode = editText.getText().toString();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data :"+passcode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("passcode");
               Query applesQuery = ref.orderByValue().equalTo(passcode);

                applesQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()){

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data doesn't exist"+passcode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        // Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                    }
                });

            }
        });
```

> This is the second way to compare firebase data.

```
btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            check = editText.getText().toString();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data :"+check, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("passcode");
           // Query applesQuery = ref.child("Customers").orderByChild("abhishek88666kumar").equalTo(passcode);

            ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    if(map.get("abhishek88666kumar")!=null){
                        passcode = map.get("abhishek88666kumar").toString();

                        if (passcode.equals(check))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else{


                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data doesn't exist"+check, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    // Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

Both are working.
Hope it's help full for you.
thank you.